# Render_to_string and response.content.decode() not matching

Tags: python, django, html

I'm writing my first `Django` app by following along with this book:

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch05.html#_passing_python_variables_to_be_rendered_in_the_template

In the book there is a test that is verifying that the html is being returned as it is supposed to.  Here is the test:

```
def test_home_page_returns_correct_html(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        response = home_page(request)
        expected_html = render_to_string('home.html')
        print(expected_html)
        print(response.content.decode())
        self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
```

My test is failing on the `assertEqual` test because I have added a `csrf token` in my HTML using the `Django Template Language`.  Here is what my HTML page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To-Do lists</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>
    <form method="POST">
            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item"/>
            {% csrf_token %}
    </form>

    <table id="id_list_table">
        <tr><td>{{ new_item_list }}</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My assert is failing due to the `render_to_string` method not including the token.  Here is what my two `print` statements included in my test print out:

```
F<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To-Do lists</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>
    <form method="POST">
            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item"/>

    </form>

    <table id="id_list_table">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To-Do lists</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>
    <form method="POST">
            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item"/>
            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='VAiGvXZLHCjxWEWdjhgQRBwBSnMVoIWR' />
    </form>

    <table id="id_list_table">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
F.
```

He doesn't have this problem in the book (he's using `1.8`), so I was wondering if the method behavior has changed, or how I would write this test to pass.

Comment: The Test Driven Development book was originally written for Django 1.7. It looks like this part might have been missed when the book was upgraded to Django 1.8.

Comment: author here.  it's actually correct for 1.8, the bug happens when you switch to 1.9.  the installation instructions in the book do clearly say you have to stick to 1.8, mumble grumble...

Comment: @hwjp My mistake, the test does pass in Django 1.8, the installation instructions do clearly say to stick to 1.8. I was using Django 1.9 when I thought I was testing 1.8. Oops!

Comment: Hey the author himself responded!  Love the book, and thanks for putting it online for free!  I figured that using 1.9 would give me a good chance to do that debugging you talked about in one of the first chapters;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `request` argument was added to [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) in Django 1.8. You could try changing the line in your test to:

```
expected_html = render_to_string('home.html', request=request)
```

It's only required to make this change in Django 1.9+, the test passes without the request in Django 1.8.

Comment: The `request` argument was added in 1.8, but you only need to update the line in Django 1.9+. The test passes without the `request` in Django 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution which has worked for the latest Django version - 3.0.6

```
#add a function to the post request test function
def remove_csrf_tag(text):
    """Remove csrf tag from TEXT"""
    return re.sub(r'<[^>]*csrfmiddlewaretoken[^>]*>', '', text)

...
# then change assertion 
def test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
...
 self.assertEqual(
        remove_csrf_tag(response.content),
        remove_csrf_tag(expected_html)
    )
```