# Stuck with Test-Driven Development with Python (chapter 6)

Tags: django, tdd

I learn Test-Driven Development with Python by Harry Percival.

I stuck in the beginning of chapter  6 approximately here:

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch06.html#_running_just_the_unit_tests

To be more precise at the point of "python3 manage.py test lists".

Let's quote the problematic code:

```
lists/tests.py
class HomePageTest(TestCase):

    def test_home_page_returns_correct_html(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        response = home_page(request)
        expected_html = render_to_string('home.html')
        self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)

lists/views.py
def home_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['item_text'])
        return redirect('/')

    items = Item.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'items': items})

lists/templates/home.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To-Do lists</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item" />
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>

        <table id="id_list_table">
            {% for item in items %}
                <tr><td>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ item.text }}</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The whole code from the previous chapter (number 5) is here: https://github.com/hjwp/book-example/tree/chapter_05

The tests in lists application were not changed since chapter 5. 
At the point where I stuck, all tests from **lists** application pass (according to the book).

But I get this:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_home_page_returns_correct_html (lists.tests.HomePageTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/superlists/lists/tests.py", line 20, in test_home_page_returns_correct_html
    self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
AssertionError: '<htm[238 chars]     <input type=\'hidden\' name=\'csrfmiddlew[163 chars]l>\n' != '<htm[238 char
s]     \n        </form>\n\n        <table id="i[66 chars]l>\n'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I try to evaluate expression in the debugger and get this:

```
"expected_html" SafeText:        <html>\n    <head>\n        <title>To-Do lists</title>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>\n        <form method="POST">\n            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item" />\n            \n        </form>\n\n        <table id="id_list_table">\n            \n        </table>\n    </body>\n</html>\n 

"response.content.decode()" str: <html>\n    <head>\n        <title>To-Do lists</title>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>\n        <form method="POST">\n            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item" />\n            \n        </form>\n\n        <table id="id_list_table">\n            \n        </table>\n    </body>\n</html>\n
```

Well, first one is SafeText and the second one is str.

If I convert expected_html to string (expected_html = str(render_to_string('home.html')), the test still fails:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_home_page_returns_correct_html (lists.tests.HomePageTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/superlists/lists/tests.py", line 20, in test_home_page_returns_correct_html
    self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
AssertionError: '<htm[238 chars]     <input type=\'hidden\' name=\'csrfmiddlew[163 chars]l>\n' != '<htm[238 char
s]     \n        </form>\n\n        <table id="i[66 chars]l>\n'
  <html>
      <head>
          <title>To-Do lists</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>
          <form method="POST">
              <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item" />
-             <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='08xKa5oXRi6EEsEBmAqONg8ATnKeqXOE' />
+             
          </form>

          <table id="id_list_table">

          </table>
      </body>
  </html>
```

Could you give me a kick here to pass the test?

Comment: Have you checked what is the type of response.content?

Comment: It is bytes. That's why we have to apply decode(). Can't catch your idea, pardon.

Comment: I can't catch the idea here. I have already converted everything to string:                     expected_html = str(render_to_string('home.html'))
        received_html = str(response.content.decode())
Then in the debugger I have checked expected_html == received_html and it is True. Why the self.assertEqual(received_html, expected_html) geves me a failure?

Comment: self.assertEqual is buggy sometimes. If what you say is true, try doing something like
`self.assertTrue(received_html == expected_html)` and see if it passes. You are basically checking the same thing here as well.

Comment: It looks like you are using Django 1.9. The book is written for Django 1.8. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928559/render-to-string-and-response-content-decode-not-matching).

Comment: @Alasdair 10, thank you. I looked at that answer. Should I use expected_html = render_to_string('home.html', request=request), the test really passes. But I seem to use Django 1.8.4. What I did: 1) Created virtualenv. 2) Cloned the project from github. 3) In Eclipse with PyDev imported the folder and converted it into Django project. 4) Chose the interpreter from virtualenv. Then I checked the Django version: url(r'^ver$', views.check_version, name='ver') and def check_version(request):
    return HttpResponse(django.VERSION) And when go to http://localhost:8000/ver, I get this: 184final0.

Comment: So, I seem to use the recommended Django version. Maybe it is a bug in the book?

Comment: I tested the code with Django 1.8 when I answered the other question, and it worked. Make sure you are using Django 1.8 when you actually run the test.

Comment: @Alasdair, thank you. You really helped. In Eclipse I really run Django 1.8. But in the very eclipse from command line I did run tests by using Django 1.9. So, I had to activate virtualenv and then tests pass as written in the book. If you shape your comment as a real answer, I could gladly accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.